# Datetime object- Extract the values

Tags: pyqt5

Using QT designer i have a date and time object like below
[image]

How can i extract the time and date entered in this one by one, i.e

```
Hour = 03 (since it is AM)
Minutes= 00
Seconds = 00
Date = 01
month= 01
year=2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strptime()` to convert strings to datetime objects.

```
from datetime import datetime

entry_date = "01/01/2000"    # string from the first widget
entry_time = "3:00 AM"       # string from the second widget

entry = datetime.strptime(entry_date + entry_time, "%d/%m/%Y%I:%M %p")
```

Then you access individual time and date components like this:

```
print(entry.year, entry.month, entry.day)
print(entry.hour, entry.minute, entry.second)
```

Output:

```
2000 1 1
3 0 0
```

If you need zero-padded values, use `strftime()` to convert datetime objects back to strings. For example:

```
print("Month =", entry.strftime("%m"))
print("Date =", entry.strftime("%d"))
```

Output:

```
Month = 01
Date = 01
```

See [this table](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) for all possible formatting tokens.

#### UPDATE:

(I assume you are using the widgets QDateEdit and QTimeEdit)

Suppose your widgets are called `entryDate` and `entryTime`. Then you would get the individual strings like this:

```
self.entryDate.date().toString("yyyy")
self.entryDate.date().toString("MM")
self.entryDate.date().toString("dd")
self.entryTime.time().toString("hh")
self.entryTime.time().toString("mm")
self.entryTime.time().toString("ss")
```

[Here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#toString) are the values to play with. (tested in PySide2 but this should work in PyQt5)

Comment: how can i store them in a variable and pass that into another function that is outside of this class